# Map or Edit Query String Values in Views?

Tags: 7, views

As part of a port of a non-Drupal site to Drupal, I need to map a url query string to filters.

For example, if I have this query string and slect filter selected on Site A (Non-Drupal)

**Site A**

Value 1 | Value 1

Value 2 | Value 2

Value 3 | Value 3

www.sitea.com/?value=value%1

**Site B:**

Value 1 |1

Value 2 |2

Value 3 |3

www.sitea.com/?value=1

Site A cannot be edited. Is it possible to either edit the values in Site B to match that of site A (within views only, not actual field data) or map the query string, so that Views will see  "www.sitea.com/?value=value%1" and display "www.sitea.com/?value=1"

I know I can change the Filter identifier (i.e. ?value)  on the filter settings tab but how can I changed the values themselves?

In reality, they are far more complex than this so I'd like to avoid HTACESS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [hook_views_pre_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/7.x-3.x) function in your custom module to change the query parameters using PHP, so a rough untested example of the code could look something like:

```
function MODULE_views_pre_view(&$view) {
  switch ($view->name) {
    case 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME': {
      // change your query strings to
      if ($_GET['value']) {
        $value = $_GET['value'];
        $new_value = substr($value, 0 , 6); // remove the 'value%' from Site A querystring
        $_GET['value'] = $new_value;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the module [Views Contextual Filter Query](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filter_query) It will fit your needs.
[image]

Comment: this module queries to be used as contextual filters but how can it be used to map/rename query string values?